# Fully offline instalable distribution

Tags: linux

My quite limited knowledge says that only major Linux distribution that offered ALL packages from distro repositories to be downloaded offline for non network install was CentOS. Are there any other distribution that offer the same (download main install iso and X amount of others containing packages)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian also provides installation media allowing complete offline installations. For the current release, the full set is available [as Jigdo templates](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/jigdo-dvd/) (that link points to 64-bit x86 DVD images; others are available). You’ll need [the `jigdo` tool](https://www.debian.org/CD/jigdo-cd/) to download them and produce the images.

You can also directly download [a DVD image of the first DVD](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-dvd/) (again for 64-bit x86), which allows offline installation with a large selection of packages, including the default GNOME desktop.

Slackware is another option, it provides [full sets of CD or DVD installation images](http://www.slackware.com/getslack/torrents.php).